# Autolayout — Padding between views

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

I have a question about padding between views (when using AutoLayout).

How can I configure AutoLayout so that when content in block is missing, it should "turn off" block and its padding too?

For example when I set up vertical padding before and after to **10 pts**, set empty string as content, I get label with 0 height and **20 pts** of "padding" space around. Actually I want this view to be hidden.

Is it possible with Autolayout or I should manually hide/show view in content setter?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I'd say you need to handle this in code. Autolayout deals with the **layout** of objects on a view. Adding or removing objects from a view is not the same thing.